# Regular expression Help for Identifier in Lexical analyser

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, lexer, regular-language, computation-theory

I am trying to make a lexer , i don't want to use **lex** file because i want to learn , so come to the point i want to make regular expression for an identifier following constraints:

'__' cannot be an identifier. 
underscore always with some letter.
Id contain at least one underscore.
underscore cannot be last symbol of id.
Must have one or more digit.
Not start with Digit.

Now regular expression I've done so far:

```
([_a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[_a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9]*[_a-zA-Z]*)*
```

Problem is i can't perform constraint about 'at least one _' in identifier , I can't make it more complex because i have to convert this regular expression to Non deterministic finite automaton , so could you help.

Comment: just edited my description

Comment: It's easy to require "at least one A" in a string: just say `[AB]*A[AB]*`. And **all** regular expressions can be turned into NFAs and DFAs -you're not using any regex features here that would make your language non-regular.

Comment: yes i know but as you can see there are other underscore related constraints in question , now R.A is bit complex and i can't find its place where i should place underscore within or where i should place repeating path

Comment: Just FYI, `XX*` can be shortened to `X+` (this pattern can be found twice in your regex).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "underscore always with some letter"? Do you mean every underscore must be followed by a letter? Or do you mean that every underscore must either follow a letter or be followed by a letter?

Comment: On a general note, if you are building a state machine by hand, it's probably easier to draw a [railroad diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) than to work out a regular expression and then convert it back to state transitions.

Comment: @rici you can say that it is for learning purpose that's why i am doing that

Comment: You have to watch out for `_` in comments. Always use backticks to quote them, otherwise they get used as italics. So your previous comment is not readable. But if you are saying that `p__k` is correct, then you need to be more precise, because the first `_` is *not* followed by a letter.

Comment: why ? `p_` underscore is followed by letter p

Comment: In `p_` the letter is followed by the underscore, not the other way around. In `p_9`, the letter p is *also* followed by the underscore, and in `_uy_` the last underscore is also beside the letter `y`. Precision is important.

Comment: @rici the good precise answer for your question is , to make it "followed by any one letter left or right side, but the other side can be anything else"

Comment: So what is wrong with `p_9`, `t_5` and `_uy_`? In all of those, the underscore has a letter on either the left or the right.

Comment: sorry it was typo , correct can be `_uy9` , `p_9`,`p_p9` wrong are `_uy_` , `p__9`,`y_9u`,`y_y`,`7_y`,`__`

Comment: And the problem with `y_9u`? `y_y`? `7_y`? In all three, the underscore is beside a `y`.

Comment: oops `y_9u` is correct , but `y_y` don't contain digit , `7_y` contain digit but first character cannot be digit

Answer (score 2):

You have specified the following constraints:

- may contain letters, digits, and underscores.
- must contain at least one digit
- must contain at least one underscore
- must not end with underscore
- must not start with digit

The “at least one X”-type constraints correspond to *states* in a state machine. Since we have two of these constraints, there are 2*2=4 states that manage whether we still need a digit or an underscore. I'll abbreviate the states:

- **DU** – needs digit, needs underscore
- **Du** – needs digit, has underscore
- **dU** – has digit, needs underscore
- **du** – has digit, has underscore

We can now create a state transition table:

```
STATE TRANSITIONS
      _  0-9 a-zA-Z
----- -- --- ------
 DU   Du dU  DU
 Du   Du du  Du
 dU   du dU  dU
 du   du du  du
```

where `DU` is the starting state. You have additional special requirements for the first and last state transition. Also, the end state can only be reached from the `du` state. Actually, `du` might itself be the end state if it wasn't reached via a `_` input. Together with these other requirements, we get the following state transition table. The start state is `S`, and terminal states are marked with a `*`. I've left out illegal transitions.

```
STATE TRANSITIONS
       _  0-9 a-zA-Z
----- --- --- -----
 S    Du   -   DU
 DU   Du  dU   DU
 Du   Du  du   Du
 dU   du' dU   dU
*du   du' du   du
 du'  du' du   du
```

The state `du'` is the “we've seen everything that we need, but the last symbol was an underscore so we can't end here”-state. This state table does not force any underscore to be followed by a letter, but you should be able to add that yourself using a similar approach. The state table corresponds to a DFA, but I doubt you could simplify it by using an NFA.

We can now translate this state machine to a regular expression, but this is a bit tedious since we have six states (conjecture: the presented state machine is already minimal). By iteratively combining state transitions into regexes fragments and eliminating states, we end up with this regex:

```
([_][_a-zA-Z]*[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*([_][_a-zA-Z]*[0-9]|[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]*[_]+[0-9a-zA-Z]))[0-9a-zA-Z]*([_]+[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*
```

Well, unless I made a mistake. Which at this point is pretty likely.

For this kind of validation, it is cumbersome to use regexes. Instead, use a simpler pattern like `[_a-zA-Z][_0-9a-zA-Z]+` and check afterwards that the matched string contains a digit and an underscore, and follows the other rules regarding underscores. This works well if the identifiers are somehow delimited in the input language, e.g. by whitespace or other non-identifier characters.

Comment: you reverse the whole process to achieve this simple task why ? i appreciate your answer but just curious

Comment: @Zulqurnainjutt Just because regexes and automata are equivalent does not mean that I always prefer using regexes. Look at the final regex: it is long and complicated, and I could have never figured it out “just like that”. However, the problem has a very concise and simple description when we phrase it in terms of states and state transitions. I found the state machine much easier to work with. (It also helped that I recently took a course on formal languages and state machines where we had to do similar problems.)

Comment: Your answer is working on identifier 'd_3__abc2e' ,why is that ? because after 2nd underscore there is an operator '_' on right and 'digit' on left where is letter ? then it should not accept it.